# Duda con consulta y foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de entender por que se hace un foreach en este ejemplo:
Tengo una funcion como:

```
function obtenerNombreProyecto($id = null){
    include 'conexion.php';
    try{
        return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id}"); 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Error! : " . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

y despues se pinta con:

```
<?php
            $proyecto = obtenerNombreProyecto($id_proyecto); 
echo var_dump($proyecto); //hago un var_dump para ver que sale
            foreach($proyecto as $nombre): 
        ?>
                <span><?php echo $nombre['nombre']; ?></span>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Las tabla que consulta tiene id y nombre solo como campos. El resultado de  la consulta seria un valor nombre ¿no es asi? ¿Por que se necesita un foreach? 
El resultado de var_dump($proyecto) es:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

¿por que? ¿no deberia ser el resultado el valor de "nombre" tal y como se hace en la consulta?

Comment: lo que sucede es que el query te devuelve un elemeto de tipo resul, en realidad no es necesario el foreach, solo con uno de los fetch estaria, ya que solo trae un dato

Comment: una cuestion: foreach funciona solo con arrays. En este ejemplo concreto ¿cual seria el array que trabajaria? ¿un array de un solo elemento? Lo digo porque el query solo traería un valor de nombre ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quiere es omitir el `foreach` entonces podria hacerlo asi:

```
function obtenerNombreProyecto($id = null){ 
    include 'conexion.php'; 
    try{ 
    return $conn->query("SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = $id"); 
    //las llaves permiten inyectar el $id 
    } catch(Exception $e) { 
        echo "Error! : " . $e->getMessage(); return false; } 
    }
    //trae un objeto de tipo result
    $proyecto = obtenerNombreProyecto($id_proyecto); 
    //utilizamos mysqli_fetch_array para que devuelva un array de tipo asociativo
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($proyecto);
        ?>
                        //ya podemos imprimir la casilla que quieres
            <span><?php echo $resultado['nombre']; ?></span>
```

Espero te sirve Bro...